# Как удалить тэг из html

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть в html тэги  Хочу их удалить

Пробую:

```
$htmlmod = str_replace(array('/<var(.*?)>/', '</var>'), '', $htmlmod);
```

Нифига не выходит( Подскажите как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это удалит ВСЕ HTML тэги, оставит только текст.

```
$htmlmod = strip_tags($htmlmod);
```

Документация:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

---

Вот это удалит все тэги `p` и `div` и `var`.

```
$htmlmod = preg_replace('/<(p|div|var).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/ism', '$2', $htmlmod);
```

Comment: мне не нужно удалять весь html, нужно только конкретные теги, но сам внутренний текст оставить

Comment: Так текст останется.... Еще раз: вам нужно удалить ВСЕ html тэги или только определенный набор тэгов? скажем, только `p, div, img`?

Comment: удалить тэг var

Comment: ответ обновлен..